# QC : How to Find a test in QC by test case id using OTA API in C#

Tags: c#, hp-quality-center

I am using OTA API in C#.

How can I find a test in QC, if I am having test case ID. (Find Test by Test Case Id)
Test may present under any folder in Test Plan.(i.e Under SUbject).

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have an open connection and know a test with that ID exists (e.g. results from a previous query), you can do the following:

```
int testId = 1234;
TestFactory tf = connection.TestFactory;
Test t = tf[id];
```

The call to the TestFactory indexer will raise a COMException with "Item does not exist." if a test with that ID does not exist.

If you don't know for sure if a test with that ID exists, you can do the following:

```
int testId = 1234;
TestFactory tf = connection.TestFactory;
TDFilter filter = tf.Filter;
filter["TS_TEST_ID"] = id.ToString();
List tests = tf.NewList(filter.Text); // List collection is the ALM List, not .NET BCL List.
Test t = (tests.Count > 0) ? tests[1] : null; // ALM List collection indexes are 1-based, and test ID is guaranteed to be unique and only return 1 result if it exists.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create filter on Conection. Example below searches test by it's name, but if you'll change "TS_TEST_NAME" on "TS_TEST_ID" you'll be able to search using test ID.

```
public int findTestCase(TDAPIOLELib.TDConnection connection, string testCaseName)
        {
            TestFactory tstF = connection.TestFactory as TestFactory;
            TDFilter testCaseFilter = tstF.Filter as TDFilter;
            testCaseFilter["TS_TEST_NAME"] = testCaseName;
            List testsList = tstF.NewList(testCaseFilter.Text);
            if(testsList != null && testsList.Count == 1)
            {
                log.log("Test case " +testCaseName+ " was found ");
                Test tmp =  testsList[0] as Test;
                return (int)tmp.ID;
            }

        return -1;
    }
```